# FCM data notifications history

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

My server is sending data messages using **FCM** to Android devices.
Is there any way to see stats on notification level? I need a number of sent messages, a number of received messages, and a number of opened messages, for every notification.

I can get those stats on daily basis using Google Analytics for a number of received and opened messages, and **FCM** connected with **PlayStore** console for a number of sent messages.

Comment: You're already aware on where you can get the data you are asking for. Sorry. What's the question?

Comment: How to get number of sent, received and opened messages per notification?
If I sent notification1 to 50 devices, and notification2 to 100 devices. I can know that 120 notifications is received, and 20 opened.
But I don't know how to get data for notification1 and notification2.

Comment: You said you're able to get it via Google Analytics..? Isn't that also visible on the Google Play Dev Console for in Diagnostics and Statistics?

Comment: It's really hard to combine data from server and app on same GA page, and also it's hard to make it work per notification. There must be some way to get that data in Firebase console, but I don't know how.

And data are visible, but only on daily basis.

Comment: I see. That's what you should include in the post since it's a little bit confusing. :)